# How to resize form and make center on page, and also resize automaticaly?

Tags: html, css

I have a blank page with a form and I am trying to resize it and then centre it in the middle of the page, I have tried using margin: auto, divs, containers,rows, etc, and it just is not working?

```css
.search-form {
  width: 800px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}

.search-input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<form class='search-form' action="{% url 'search-results' %}" method='get'>
  <input class='search-input' name='q' type='text' placeholder='Enter keywords here'>
</form>
```

I have it in the center of the page now, but I still need it to resize when I resize the browser etc?

UPDATE - CSS -

```
'''
.search-form {
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: auto;

}

.search-input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
'''
```

It is now working now. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and add any relevant CSS showing what you've attempted.

Comment: We can't possibly help if you don't show what you've tried - share your css as well

Comment: Ok I will try and update, I have tried many things, and it hasn't worked... obv I am doing something wrong, and I have deleted the css code, I presumed someone could of just told me how to do it correctly without me showing some css code that doesn't work anyway?

Comment: That looks like bootstrap grid or something similar right? Then there's [responsive breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#responsive-classes) already available for the exact purpose you're describing that you might want to check out before you over-engineer something.

Comment: You are setting an explicit `width` on the search form. It will never change from that. Set `width` to `100%` and create a `max-width: 800px`

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think I am starting to figure it out now

Comment: Thanks, disinfor.. that worked a treat.

Comment: no problem! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using bootstrap, you first need to change col-sm-1 to just col-sm.
Bootstrap runs on a grid system and you can specify how many columns you want in very different ways. They support up to 12 columns where col-sm-1 will take up one column space, and col-sm-6 will take up 6 of the 12 (half the page). If you remove the number it will size to the maximum size that it can be along with its sibling elements. You probably want to also set your form to be a relative width which will allow it to grow and shrink with the page. There are different ways to do this. Some people use max-width, and others use percentages. Lot's of ways to do what you are tryin to accomplish. Both examples are in the code snippet below. Ignore the link tag... that's just so that the example works.

```css
form {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Search Form -->
<div class='sb'>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
          <form class='search-form' action="{% url 'search-results' %}" method='get'>
              <input class='search-input' name='q' type='text' placeholder='Enter keywords here'>
          </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you look at the CSS - the `.search-form` has a `width: 800px;` - that's the problem. Answer is already in the comments.

Comment: My bad. I posted my answer before they updated with their CSS

Comment: Thanks tho I appreciate it none the less.